# Deploy .net application using command Line

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, continuous-deployment, web-deployment-project

I have an .WPF application.Using XBAP project the project as web application. The solution file having 15 projects. Among 15 projects, one is root project names 'cp'. This has other project dll. i am able to build the code. My goal is that to Publish in one Location (Ex: c:\publish)in the file format of '.deploy' of all the project(Ex: sampleproject.dll.deploy).  How command should i use.? I have tried following command one by one. Nothing give proper .deploy package.

R&D

```
msbuild cp.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Test
msbuild cp.sln  /p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder;PackageTempRootDir="C:\Publish";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false 
msbuild cp.sln  /p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package      
msbuild cp.sln  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FileSystemDebug
msbuild cp.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myprofile
msbuild cp.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myprofile.
msbuild cp.csproj "/p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release;PublishDestination=C:\Publish" /t:PublishToFileSystem
```

Comment: I recall reading something about console apps not being able to interact with the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your publish profile and publish directory is "c:\publish" you should use the following windows commands. I suppose that You are using MSbuild 14.0.

**For Windows Machine**
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="C:\PublishProfiles\testprofile.pubxml" "C:\Myapp\Myproject.sln"

**For Azure**
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:PublishProfile="C:\PublishProfiles\testprofile.pubxml" /p:Password=xxxxx "C:\Myapp\Myproject.sln"